# KVM Server error

Tags: linux, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I have installed KVM server in Centos 6.4 and i have created gluster storage pool in that gluster storage pool i have installed some linux and window VM's i have assigned 1GB RAM and 20 GD virtual disk for linux vm and 30 GB for windows VM's... still my vm were running very slow and when trying to copy any file are directory from one VM to another vm's destination VM got hanged i am facing this problem...

Please anyone can help me to come to out from this problem...

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if there is any kind of disk I/O issue? If that disk I/O is fine, your next test would be network setup and updating drivers of NIC to the latest from your provider. Have you also setup KVM bridge network correctly?

Comment: Thanks... KVM bridge network is ok. Only i am getting this problem while copying any file from one vm to another vm and ssh...